# Given an integer $n >0$, how many ways can we express $n$ as the sum of three natural numbers $n_1,n_2,n_3$ ? 

Tags: number-theory

Given an integer $n >0$, how many ways can we express $n$ as the sum of three natural numbers $n_1,n_2,n_3$ ?

Comment: That definition doesn't define a function.

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean by "cardinality of $f(n)$" as this is just one element of $\mathbb{N}^3$. If you want to phrase your question with the help of a function then you are more likely asking for the cardinalities of the fibers of the map $g: \mathbb{N}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}, (n_1,n_2,n_3) \mapsto n_1+n_2+n_3$.

Comment: The function made things confusing, I have edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Judging by the comments and other answer I think I might be missing out on something. yet- This might still be right, so I post this answer, please let me know if I'm horribly wrong :-)*

---

I think we this question can be reformulated in the following manner:

Suppose we have $n+2$ balls, $n$ of which are white, and the other two are black. Now, each different way in which you order the $n+2$ balls gives you a different partition of $n$ in to $3$ natural numbers ($0$ included)- just count how many white balls are between any two black ones.

Moreover- any partition of $n$ to naturals $n_1+n_2+n_3=n$, can be visualized as an ordering of the above $n+2$ balls:

Just put the first $n_1$ white balls in a row, followed by a black one, then the next $n_2$ white balls, followed by a black one and then the last $n_3$ white ones.

So the question reduces to how many ways can you arrage $n$ white balls, and two black ones in a row-

This is easily seen to be $\binom{n+2}{2}$.

(once the positions for the two black ones has been set, the partition is determined)

Comment: Clever! This is definitely correct. In my simplex answer, I mistakenly assumed that he wanted $n_1,n_2,n_3 > 0$, so it would give a different answer, but still, the answer would probably reduce to something quite simple, and would match a similar combinatorial formula.

Comment: This is very enlightening, thanks for making the effort to make this understandable.

Comment: @LHS: sure thing :)

Comment: @LHS:  This answer assumes that you find (1,2,3) different from (3,2,1)-that is, you are using ordered partitions.  If you want ordered partitions and require all the numbers be >0, you just have $\binom {n-1}{2}$.  The same argument holds, but you can't put black balls at the ends or next to each other.

Answer (score 4):

*I mistakenly assumed that you wanted* $n_1,n_2,n_3 > 0$, *so the following answer is not correct. I won't remove it, since I think it might still be interesting*.

It's the number of lattice points in the interior of a dilation of the [standard 2-simplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#The_standard_simplex). Then, using a change of basis, this can be changed into the question of how many lattice points lie inside 2D triangle, which can be found using [pick's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, this is still interesting like you say!